# Why Location manager returns null?

Tags: android, geolocation

I am developing an app where users will be reporting field Incidences.
The Incident location(longitude and latitude) is important for mapping purposes.

For better, i want to use GPS provider only.

In my activity, i have a nested class for getting location information.

```
private class myGPSTracker extends Service implements LocationListener {


        public myGPSTracker() {

            getLocation();
        }

        public Location getLocation() {
            try {
                locationManager = (LocationManager) context
                        .getSystemService(LOCATION_SERVICE);

                // getting GPS status
                isGPSEnabled = locationManager
                        .isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);

                // getting network status
                //isNetworkEnabled = locationManager
                // .isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER);

                if (!isGPSEnabled ) {
                    // no network provider is enabled
                    showSettingsAlert();

                    canGetLocation = true;

                    // if GPS Enabled get lat/long using GPS Services
                    if (isGPSEnabled) {

                        if ( ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(ReportIncident.this, android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION ) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED ) {

                            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(ReportIncident.this, new String[] {  android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION  }, ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION );
                        }
                        if (location == null) {
                            locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(
                                    LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER,
                                    MIN_TIME_BW_UPDATES,
                                    MIN_DISTANCE_CHANGE_FOR_UPDATES, this);
                            Log.d("GPS Enabled", "GPS Enabled");
                            if (locationManager != null) {
                                location = locationManager
                                        .getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);
                                if (location != null) {
                                    latitude = location.getLatitude();
                                    longitude = location.getLongitude();
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }



                } else {
                    canGetLocation = true;

                    // if GPS Enabled get lat/long using GPS Services
                    if (isGPSEnabled) {

                        if ( ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(ReportIncident.this, android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION ) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED ) {

                            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(ReportIncident.this, new String[] {  android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION  }, ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION );
                        }
                        if (location == null) {
                            locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(
                                    LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER,
                                    MIN_TIME_BW_UPDATES,
                                    MIN_DISTANCE_CHANGE_FOR_UPDATES, this);
                            Log.d("GPS Enabled", "GPS Enabled");
                            if (locationManager != null) {
                                location = locationManager
                                        .getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);
                                if (location != null) {
                                    latitude = location.getLatitude();
                                    longitude = location.getLongitude();
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }

            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            return location;
        }




        /**
         * Function to get latitude
         * */
        public double getLatitude(){
            if(location != null){
                latitude = location.getLatitude();
            }

            // return latitude
            return latitude;
        }

        /**
         * Function to get longitude
         * */
        public double getLongitude(){
            if(location != null){
                longitude = location.getLongitude();
            }

            // return longitude
            return longitude;
        }
        public double getAltitude()
        {
            if(location != null){
                altitude = location.getAltitude();
            }

            // return longitude
            return  altitude;
        }
        /**
         * Function to check GPS/wifi enabled
         * @return boolean
         * */


        /**
         * Function to show settings alert dialog
         * On pressing Settings button will lauch Settings Options
         * */


        @Override
        public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
        }

        @Override
        public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) {
        }

        @Override
        public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) {
        }

        @Override
        public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras) {
        }

        @Override
        public IBinder onBind(Intent arg0) {
            return null;
        }
        public String getAddress()
        {
            Geocoder geocoder =
                    new Geocoder(context, Locale.getDefault());

            // Create a list to contain the result address
            List<Address> addresses = null;
            try {
             /*
              * Return 1 address.
              */
                addresses = geocoder.getFromLocation(this.getLatitude(),
                        this.getLongitude(), 1);
            } catch (Exception e1) {
                e1.printStackTrace();
                return ("Un Known place!");
            }
            // If the reverse geocode returned an address
            if (addresses != null && addresses.size() > 0) {
                // Get the first address
                Address address = addresses.get(0);
             /*
              * Format the first line of address (if available),
              * city, and country name.
              */
                String addressText = String.format(
                        "%s, %s, %s",
                        // If there's a street address, add it
                        address.getMaxAddressLineIndex() > 0 ?
                                address.getAddressLine(0) : "",
                        // Locality is usually a city
                        address.getLocality(),
                        // The country of the address
                        address.getCountryName());
                // Return the text
                return addressText;
            } else {
                return "Un known place";
            }
        }
    }

    public void showSettingsAlert(){
        AlertDialog.Builder alertDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(ReportIncident.this);

        // Setting Dialog Title
        alertDialog.setTitle("GPS  settings");

        // Setting Dialog Message
        alertDialog.setMessage("GPS is not enabled. Do you want to go to settings menu?");

        // On pressing Settings button
        alertDialog.setPositiveButton("Settings", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog,int which) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(Settings.ACTION_LOCATION_SOURCE_SETTINGS);
                context.startActivity(intent);
            }
        });

        // on pressing cancel button
        alertDialog.setNegativeButton("Cancel", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                dialog.cancel();
            }
        });

        // Showing Alert Message
        alertDialog.show();
    }
```

In my Activity, i try to get location information by

```
gpstracker=new myGPSTracker();

  Incidents incidents =new Incidents();
                incidents.setId(new Date().getTime());
                incidents.setIncidentdate(new Date().getTime());
                incidents.setPlaceName("Some Thing");
                incidents.setAltitude(gpstracker.getAltitude());
                incidents.setMyLat(gpstracker.getLatitude());
                incidents.setMyLongtitude(gpstracker.getLongitude());
```

When i run the app, i get 0 for longitude and latitude, and i also debugged and found out the location manager is null.

Here is the complete code for the activity.

```
public class ReportIncident extends Activity {
     Button bb;

    double mylat;
    double mylong;
    String myplace;
    double myalt;
    EditText editText;
    private  Context context;
    //private Context mContext;
    // flag for GPS status
    boolean isGPSEnabled = false;

    // flag for GPS status
    boolean canGetLocation = false;
   private  myGPSTracker gpstracker;
    Location location; // location
    double latitude; // latitude
    double longitude; // longitude
    double altitude;

    // The minimum distance to change Updates in meters
    private static final long MIN_DISTANCE_CHANGE_FOR_UPDATES = 10; // 10 meters

    // The minimum time between updates in milliseconds
    private static final long MIN_TIME_BW_UPDATES = 1000 * 60 * 1; // 1 minute

    // Declaring a Location Manager
    protected LocationManager locationManager;
    private static final int  ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION = 200;
    //private Activity activity;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.add_incident);
        context=getApplicationContext();
        gpstracker=new myGPSTracker();
        editText=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.txtReportIncident);
        bb=(Button)findViewById(R.id.btnReport);

        bb.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                String mydescription=editText.getText().toString().trim();
                if(TextUtils.isEmpty(mydescription))
                {
                    editText.setError("Field can not be blank");
                    return;
                }

                Incidents incidents =new Incidents();
                incidents.setId(new Date().getTime());
                incidents.setIncidentdate(new Date().getTime());
                incidents.setPlaceName("Some Thing");
                incidents.setAltitude(gpstracker.getAltitude());
                incidents.setMyLat(gpstracker.getLatitude());
                incidents.setMyLongtitude(gpstracker.getLongitude());
                incidents.setIncidentDescription(mydescription);
                new AddIncidentAsyncTask(getApplicationContext()).execute(incidents);
                editText.setText("");
            }
        });

    }
```

What is missing?

Any help will be highly appreciated.

Ronald

Comment: I doubt that the `LocationManager` is `null`. The `Location` may be `null`, because there is no requirement for `getLastKnownLocation()` to return a non-`null` `Location`. You are registering a `LocationListener`, so put code in `onLocationChanged()` to use the `Location` then, if you do not get one from `getLastKnownLocation()`. See [the documentation](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/location/strategies.html) for more. Also, remove `extends Service` from `myGPSTracker`, as it is not a valid subclass of `Service`.

Comment: Hello, you were right!...tested the app outside and it worked!...